# Connect to Socket.IO through socket.io-emitter

Tags: socket.io

I'm running two separate node.js processes. One runs Socket.IO and another Express.js. I'm trying to send an event from Express to the server running socket.io but by using socket.io-emitter a event only reaches sockets connected to the socket.io server. What I need is to be able to observe the same event that all other sockets are receing but on the socket.io server.

Comment: Maybe I should use https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis ?

Answer (score 0):

I used node_redis for interprocess communication. There's a Publish/Subscribe feature which is just what I wanted.

There's an example as below in https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis.

```
var redis = require("redis");
var sub = redis.createClient(), pub = redis.createClient();
var msg_count = 0;

sub.on("subscribe", function (channel, count) {
    pub.publish("a nice channel", "I am sending a message.");
    pub.publish("a nice channel", "I am sending a second message.");
    pub.publish("a nice channel", "I am sending my last message.");
});

sub.on("message", function (channel, message) {
    console.log("sub channel " + channel + ": " + message);
    msg_count += 1;
    if (msg_count === 3) {
        sub.unsubscribe();
        sub.quit();
        pub.quit();
    }
});

sub.subscribe("a nice channel");
```